# Can schema changes be done within transactions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

That's pretty much all there is to my question: Can schema changes be done within transactions in MySQL?

My understanding is no but I'm not having an easy time finding documentation that provides a definitive answer.

Comment: Have you tried to run it? What do you think could go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[Implicit commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html) and [cannot rollback](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cannot-roll-back.html) sections of the mysql documentation quite clearly indicate, that schema changes should not be part of a transaction involving other commands, since they will either cause a commit, or the schema changes cannot be rolled back.

Comment: Schema changes can never be rolled back in MySQL.  They are not transactional, which is why they cause an implicit commit.